# Selecting Multiple Selectors for increased specificity in Selenium Using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<input class="radio-field" type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="value(WoundCareDone)">
```

Hey guys I just have a tiny question.

I want to select the xpath of name. It would go like this //input[@name="value(WoundCareDone)"] right?

so how I want to include the value 0 in the xpath because only using the above xpath yields 2 results. how do we include value="0" in the xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
//input[@name="value(WoundCareDone)" and @value = "0"]
```